# Drawing large images 15kx15k fast and efficiently

Tags: vb.net, opengl

I have a large 15k by 15k map of an area that I am trying to display quickly, zoom and pan. I'm currently using Leaflet in a webbrowser in my vb.net application, it works, but as I keep building upon my application its getting slowler and slower, as I'm using it for something it wasn't designed for. I have loads (100's) of graphics that move around on the map as well. I feel that because it runs off javascript and not a compiled language, that severely restricts its perfermance.

I've looked into things like DirectX and OpenGL but thats really over my head and I'm really struggling with the basics of that. I was hoping to find a library of some sort that could already draw large images efficiently with them but haven't been successful.

I just need to be able to draw the large map at this stage, not worry about the drawing of graphics at this stage.

Comment: You might try this control.  I don't know if it will help.  http://bobpowell.net/zoompicbox.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately it can't handle large images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking purely at speed of drawing, you could split the picture into a number of smaller pictures which are processed simultaneously. The most effective way of doing this would be using multiple threads.

Comment if you need more info.

Comment: Do you mean in vb.net or OpenGL? I have been slowly cracking open OpenGL but its rather difficult since I have to use OpenTK for vb so there are slight differences which cause problems. Anyway if you mean OpenGL I would have zero idea on even how to begin to do that. I have seen things in OpenGL that uses tiles and that's what I'm trying to do, but it needs to be really efficient.

Comment: I'm talking about running it only on the cpu using multiple threads. If I have some time later I'll throw something together to see the speed increase. I assume you want the zoom/pan to appear smoothly? Have you tried using lockbits? How much faster do you need?

Comment: Having it smooth isn't important, just being able to pan and zoom without it lagging horribly. I need to be able to have 15k x 15k image not lag the entire application, especially when I draw stuff on it. I'll be very interested to see how you do it though. I haven't tried lockbits, the only thing that I have found that works somewhat is Leaflet, which requires breaking the image up into tiles at various zoom levels, which I don't have a problem, but it runs in javascript and as such is slow.